# Deploy micro-frontend to Server Apache

Tags: angular, docker, apache, micro-frontend

I created a container, in this container I built an image of the apache web server (httpd) taking it from the DockerHub, I managed to upload the build of my frontend into the htdocs folder and modified the path in the path apache2/conf/httpd.conf DocumentRoot lines "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/buildApplication"
<Directory "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/buildApplicativo"> ​​Now, however, I would also like to load the FE of another project which is nothing more than the microfrontend of the first one, how can I do it?

How can I do? At the moment I have loaded the other frontend which is used as a microfrontend into the htdocs folder, but it doesn't work when I start the container, that is, it always loads the first frontend on port 80, but looking at the console with inspect, the remote module is not loaded on port 4205 ( which is the other frontend)